# Name of Wreath Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, math-history, wreath-product

Why is the [wreath product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) so named?

If possible, please provide a citation.

Comment: [Cross-posted on HSM.](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2046/history-of-the-wreath-product)

Comment: It is almost like the "wrath product", where things don't have the properties you want, so you angrily scream and tear up your draft notes.

Answer (score 2):

Charles Wells' 1976 paper *[Some Applications of the Wreath Product Construction](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/259237336_Some_Applications_of_the_Wreath_Product_Construction)* (The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 83, No. 5) states that the wreath product nomenclature came from Pólya's 1937 paper *Kombinatorische Anzahlbestimmungen für Gruppen, Graphen und chemische Verbindungen* (Pólya used the term *Kranzgruppe*).  See pages 333 and 334 of Wells' paper (journal pagination).  I don't know if Pólya discussed this choice of terminology in any of his papers or correspondence.